# javascript loop, adding a letter every time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a loop which every time will add a letter to the print screen. I think I'mm close but I cant figure out how to not show the first S of the name, here's what I mean:

```
var name = "Steve";
var newName = name[0];
```

Now the looping:

```
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){console.log(newName += name[i]);}
```

It translates to:
SS
SSt
SSte
SStev
SSteve

Comment: Either start with `newName = '';`, or start your loop with `i = 1;`

Comment: Oh jeez thanks guys :) the newName = " "; worked!

Comment: Read setting breakpoints: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp
If you stepped through the code step by step it would have been clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

More simple answer on your scenario, using substring than building the string.

```
var name = "Steve";
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){console.log(name.substring(0, i + 1));}
```

Comment: That is really useful and different from what i ve learned. Just started learning javascript through eloquent javascript and substring is completely new to me. Thanks Arnel you taught me something new !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize var name to an empty string

```
var newName = '';
```

Answer (score -1):

You're doubling the first letter because `name[0]` actually gives you the first letter of `name`.  You don't need the `newName` variable; just use `name`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){console.log(name[i]);}
```

Comment: He wants the whole string to get added to. To omit the newName varaible he'd need `for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){console.log(name.substring(0,i+1));}`

Answer (score -4):

Since you already start with first letter selected, loop from second letter `i = 1`:

```js
var name = "Steve";
var newName = name[0];

for (var i = 1; i < name.length; i++) {
  newName += name[i];
  $('body').append(newName + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He doesn't mention jquery being allowed, nor needing to append to the body. This answer doesn't really improve on the comment by Evan.

Comment: @judgeja jquery is only for displaying result instead of printing out in console.